# Removing space under a bootstrap well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using twitter bootstrap on an web application for the first time and I would like to create on a page up to 6-8 well that occupy 6 columns on a large screen.I have managed to do just that I only have one problem.

If for example the height of the well on the right is higher then the well on the left , alot of space get's left unfilled.Here is what I mean:

[image]

In order to solve this problem I thought it was as simple of setting the margin-top and margin-bottom of the well container to 0 but it did not work.This is my html structure:

```
        <section class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well overflow">
                <div class="col-xs-8 reset-padding-left">
                    <h5><strong>About Me</strong></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-right reset-padding-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 content-divider"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Birthday</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <p>15 November 1989</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Gender</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <p>Male</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Birth Place</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <p>Bacau, Romania</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well overflow">
                <div class="col-xs-8 reset-padding-left">
                    <h5><strong>About Me</strong></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-right reset-padding-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 content-divider"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left reset-padding-right">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Birthday</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-3 reset-padding-right add-margin-bottom">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option selected="selected">4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9  col-md-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 reset-padding-right add-margin-bottom">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Dec</option>
                            <option selected="selected">Nov</option>
                            <option>Jan</option>
                            <option>Feb</option>
                            <option>Mart</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9  col-md-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 reset-padding-right add-margin-bottom">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1987</option>
                            <option>1987</option>
                            <option>1987</option>
                            <option selected="selected">1986</option>
                            <option>1985</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left reset-padding-right add-margin-bottom">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Gender</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left reset-padding-right add-margin-bottom">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Birth City</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 reset-padding-left reset-padding-right">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 reset-padding-left">
                        <span>Birth Country</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 reset-padding-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I only added the structure for the first two wells if I need to add more I'l add the reset.Is there any way to make the third well come imediatly under the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set to each even column .col-sm-6 float:right instead of float:left it seems to be working

```
.col-sm-6:nth-child(even) {
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at "inspect element" to know where the space is coming from. It's probably some padding or margin.

You could add an own class to the element with the padding/margin and give that class an other or a negative margin.

Comment: I did that the wierd thing is that it does not contain any margin or padding.I even tryed reseting it by adding classes and it had no effect

Comment: Try to remove some bootstrap classes and check the result, you'll maybe discover which bootstrap class does these weird things.

Comment: The space is due to floating. Since the item to the right is also floating left and is taller when something else is floated left and must wrap it wraps to the height of the tallest item.